# Does std::stringstream operator<< use strcat?

Tags: c++, string, std

I have just learned of the "Schlemiel the painter" algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm) and realized I might be Schlemiel.

In my code I do a lot of string concatenation with `std::stringstream`'s `operator<<`. I was embarrassed to learn that heavy use of c-style concatenation with `strcat` has a pretty large inefficiency.

Does C++'s `std::stringstream`'s `operator<<` uses `strcat`? Or does it use a more efficient method?

Comment: As I know string concatenation is more effective than doing it though stringstream https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/aiFIGb6za0w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ostringstream` is backed by a `stringbuf`, which inherits from `streambuf`; when writing to an `ostringstream` you are writing to the *controlled output sequence* of the `streambuf`.  According to 27.6.2:

> 2 - Each sequence is characterized by three pointers [...]
>
> - the *beginning pointer*, or lowest element address in the array [...]
> - the *next pointer*, or next element address that is a current candidate for reading or writing [...]
> - the *end pointer*, or first element address beyond the end of the array [...]

So an `ostringstream` effectively has constant time access to the current end of its output sequence.

Note that using `strlen` on the output sequence would not work, anyway, as C++ strings are allowed to contain embedded nul characters.

Also note that direct string concatenation (`string::operator+=(const string &)`) is likely to be more efficient than `ostream` operators, as there is no requirement to go via virtual methods.